# Call method from jsp

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

Is it possible in jsp to call a method from controller automatically every 2 seconds without pressing a button/link? The purpose would be to update some data dynamically in the page.

Comment: to call automatically a **method from controller**? from controller or from jsp page u want to call a method?

Comment: The application uses SpringMVC. I have a Controller with a GET method which displays some data in a page. In jsp I would like to call this method, in order to update the displayed data, but this needs to be done without pressing some button.

Comment: create a javaScript function which will make a ajax call after 2 sec and update the content in ur jsp page using the ajax response.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible and you can use Ajax for this.

First using JavaScript create a function and using `setInterval()` call this function every 2 seconds as,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(myFun, 2000);
});
function myFun(){

    $.get("ControllerName", function(data){
        alert("Data: " + data);
        //You can use "data" to update whatever you want 
    });

}
```

Within you controller whatever you write within `out.print()` will be sent to the JSP page.

```
out.print(new Date());
```

Make sure to import jQuery in your JSP page.

Answer (score 0):

User [Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) for asynchronous communication between client and serve which will happen without any client page refresh. And for every 2 second part use JS [WindowTimers.setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval)

Answer (score -1):

You can Auto refresh the JSP page where your method is present.
This is possible by invoking the setIntHeader() method of the response object.
You need to provide the interval for the refresh.In your case it is 2 seconds.

e.g. response.setIntHeader("Refresh", 2);

Comment: refreshing the page, can we make a call to a particular method? Is it really possible?